# How to select a GPU with CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a computer with 2 GPUs; I wrote a CUDA C program and I need to tell it somehow that I want to run it on just 1 out of the 2 graphic cards; what is the command I need to type and how should I use it? I believe somehow that is related to the *cudaSetDevice* but I can't really find out how to use it.

Comment: Question might be a bit unclear, do you actually "want to run it on just 1 out of the 2 graphic cards" or "want to run it on the first of the 2 graphic cards" ? Because the first requirement is satisfied already, unless you create an app which _forces_ the use of all your available GPUs.

Comment: What I want to do is just select the graphic card I want: in my case the second one.

Comment: How is that second card specific? based on what information you want to select it? Compute capability or something else?

Comment: I'd like to select it based on the number of cuda cores... basically i need to use the most powerfull

Comment: Number of cores really is not a very good metric... See that [GTX 580](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-580/specifications) has almost two times less cores than [GTX 660](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-660/specifications) while GTX 580 is superior in terms of performance. This is a result of architectural changes that happened between Fermi and Kepler.

Comment: haha ok ok but I'm 100% sure that the first one I have is super slow so no worries

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be pretty much clear from [documentation of `cudaSetDevice`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g159587909ffa0791bbe4b40187a4c6bb), but let me provide following code snippet.

```
bool IsGpuAvailable()
{
    int devicesCount;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&devicesCount);
    for(int deviceIndex = 0; deviceIndex < devicesCount; ++deviceIndex)
    {
        cudaDeviceProp deviceProperties;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProperties, deviceIndex);
        if (deviceProperties.major >= 2
            && deviceProperties.minor >= 0)
        {
            cudaSetDevice(deviceIndex);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is how I iterated through all available GPUs (`cudaGetDeviceCount`) looking for the first one of Compute Capability of at least 2.0. If such device was found, then I used `cudaSetDevice` so all the CUDA computations were executed on that particular device. Without executing the `cudaSetDevice` your CUDA app would execute on the first GPU, i.e. the one with `deviceIndex == 0` but which particular GPU is that depends on which GPU is in which PCIe slot.

**EDIT:**

After clarifying your question in comments, it seems to me that it should be suitable for you to choose the device based on its name. If you are unsure about your actual GPU names, then run this code which will print names of all your GPUs into console:

```
int devicesCount;
cudaGetDeviceCount(&devicesCount);
for(int deviceIndex = 0; deviceIndex < devicesCount; ++deviceIndex)
{
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProperties;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProperties, deviceIndex);
    cout << deviceProperties.name << endl;
}
```

After that, choose the name of the GPU that you want to use for computations, lets say it is `"GTX XYZ"`. Call the following method from your `main` method, thanks to it, all the CUDA kernels will be executed on the device with name `"GTX XYZ"`. You should also check the return value - `true` if device with such name is found, `false` otherwise:

```
bool SetGPU()
{
    int devicesCount;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&devicesCount);
    string desiredDeviceName = "GTX XYZ";
    for(int deviceIndex = 0; deviceIndex < devicesCount; ++deviceIndex)
    {
        cudaDeviceProp deviceProperties;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProperties, deviceIndex);
        if (deviceProperties.name == desiredDeviceName)
        {
            cudaSetDevice(deviceIndex);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Of course you have to change the value of `desiredDeviceName` variable to desired value.

Comment: So baiscally I should copy this lines in my main program and then type "cudaSetDevice" before the kernel call?

Comment: @FedericoGentile please see the **EDIT** section of my answer, it should solve your situation.

Comment: just kidding... the first part where I identify the name of the gpu works correctly; however when i try the second part it says that there's something wrong with bool: it says it's missing a ";" but I can't see where!

Comment: [Here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-always-set-current-device-avoid-multithreading-bugs/) is some useful info on `cudaSetDevice` when dealing with threads.

Answer (score 2):

Searching more carefully in the internet I found this lines of code that select the GPU with more cores among all the devices installed in the Pc.

```
int num_devices, device;
cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_devices);
if (num_devices > 1) {
  int max_multiprocessors = 0, max_device = 0;
  for (device = 0; device < num_devices; device++) {
          cudaDeviceProp properties;
          cudaGetDeviceProperties(&properties, device);
          if (max_multiprocessors < properties.multiProcessorCount) {
                  max_multiprocessors = properties.multiProcessorCount;
                  max_device = device;
          }
  }
  cudaSetDevice(max_device);
}
```