# How to know in which graphic card my program runs?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm using two graphic cards to test with some programs in CUDA. I think one of them is broken but the computer still recognizing it. How do I switch the "main graphic card" to run my program (if this exists) and discover if they are working properly?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31628407/7968757) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28112485/7968757) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-always-set-current-device-avoid-multithreading-bugs/) might help. You can use `cudaSetDevice` to select which GPU you want to run on. You can also run `nvidia-smi` from the command line to check which devices are visible on your system. Just be careful, the order from nvidia-smi is in PCIe order, while the driver and runtime do not guarantee that.

You can use `cudaGetDeviceCount` to get the total number of visible devices, and then just loop that times, calling `cudaSetDevice` with the index of the loop as an argument to set a new device to run on.

Hope this helps!