# cudaGetDeviceCount returns error: 1 invalid argument

Tags: cuda

Running this code:

```
int device = 0;
cudaGetDevice(&device);
cudaDeviceProp props;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, device);
const int kb = 1024;
const int mb = kb * kb;

cout << "Module Start:" << endl;
cout << props.name << ": " << props.major << "." << props.minor << endl;
cout << "  Global memory:   " << props.totalGlobalMem / mb << "mb" << endl;
cout << "  Shared memory:   " << props.sharedMemPerBlock / kb << "kb" << endl;
cout << "  Constant memory: " << props.totalConstMem / kb << "kb" << endl;
cout << "  Block registers: " << props.regsPerBlock << endl;
cout << "  Warp size:         " << props.warpSize << endl;
cout << "  Threads per block: " << props.maxThreadsPerBlock << endl;
cout << "  Max block dimensions: [ " << props.maxThreadsDim[0] << ", " << props.maxThreadsDim[1] << ", " << props.maxThreadsDim[2] << " ]" << endl;
cout << "  Max grid dimensions:  [ " << props.maxGridSize[0] << ", " << props.maxGridSize[1] << ", " << props.maxGridSize[2] << " ]" << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Results in the following garbage output and crash on RTX 2060, x64 Windows 10 on friend's computer:

[image: error output]

EDIT:
I added some error checks:

```
int devicesCount;
cudaError_t error_id = cudaGetDeviceCount(&devicesCount);

if (error_id != cudaSuccess) {
    printf("cudaGetDeviceCount returned %d\n%s\n", (int)error_id, cudaGetErrorString(error_id));
    return 1;
} else {
    printf("Found %d GPUs\n", devicesCount);
}
```

and this is the error:
`cudaGetDeviceCount` returns error: "return 1, invalid argument"

It also appears he is using Windows insider edition and Driver Version *465.21*, which is newer than the current stable release.

Works on the 1070, x64 Windows 10:

[image]

I tried using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112485/how-to-select-a-gpu-with-cuda) to get and set the active device, but that gave the same garbage output.

I am compiling to a .DLL and calling the functions through Python. It is possible that my Visual Studio project settings got messed up somehow, because it was working on friend's 2060 before.

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -gencode=arch=compute_37,code=\"sm_37,compute_37\" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=\"sm_60,compute_60\" -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=\"sm_61,compute_61\" -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=\"sm_70,compute_70\" -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=\"sm_75,compute_75\" -gencode=arch=compute_80,code=\"sm_80,compute_80\" -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=\"sm_86,compute_86\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I./ -I../../common/inc -I./ -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\/include" -I../../common/inc -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart shared --threads 0   -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -D_WINDLL -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Fdx64/Release/vc142.pdb /FS   /MD " -o x64/Release/gpu_compute.cu.obj "D:\Tests\MyDLL\gpu_compute.cu"
```

Comment: both API calls return a status, which you should be checking

Comment: @talonmies I have added error checks, please see the Edit for the exact error. It appears this system has driver 465.21, which might be the issue.

Comment: OK so he has a broken CUDA installation somehow. There is no programming or code related question here

Comment: @talonmies that turned out to be the case, after rolling back to the current release it is now working, I posted it as an answer in case someone else has this odd issue

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by not yet released Driver Version 465.21 shipped with the Windows Insider edition. Rolling back to current 461.40 solved this.